# what is the difference between CompletableFuture methods acceptEither vs acceptEitherAsync?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

For example -

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(stage1).acceptEither(stage2, consumer );
```

stage1 and stage2 are supposed to run in parallel in above code as it is using `acceptEither`

If I change to `acceptEitherAsync`, i see I can get more control over which thread (thread from ForkJoin pool or thread from custom executor pool) runs stage2.

But on running below code ([jdoddle link)](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/Fnb) I found that **stage2** `is not running in` main` thread but in a ForkJoin pool. How is it possible.
From [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) -

> Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be
> performed by the thread that completes the current CompletableFuture,
> or by any other caller of a completion method.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
                System.out.println("hello world, CompletableFuturesRightHere");

     CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("log-sA: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("log-sA post: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return 40;
        }).acceptEither(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("log-aE: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("log-aE post: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return 80;
        }), a -> { System.out.println(a); } );
  }
}
```

Output:

```
hello world, CompletableFuturesRightHere
log-aE: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5
log-sA: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
log-aE post: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5
log-sA post: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
40
```

How can **stage2** i.e **log-aE** run in worker-5, it should run in main or worker-3. But Since stage1 and stage2 are supposed to run in parallel and worker-3 is already running stage1, the only thread left for stage2 is `main`.
**How could stage2 run in worker-5.**

Comment: The `supplyAsync` overload that _does not_ accept an `Executor` executes the given `Supplier` using the common `ForkJoinPool`. Then `acceptEither`, as stated by the documentation you linked, will execute the `Consumer` using the thread that completed one of the two previous stages or the caller thread.

Comment: In other words, the "actions" talked about in that documentation is not, in the context of `acceptEither`, the other `CompletableFuture` but rather the `Consumer`.

Comment: @slaw the pauses are commented and hence I removed them now

Comment: I ended up deleting that part of my comment. Regardless, "stage 2" is executed on "worker-5" because you've told it to be executed by one of the threads in the common `ForkJoinPool` by using `#supplyAsync(Supplier)`.

Comment: @Slaw i am not bothered about `supplyAsync` i.e stage1 and `consumer` thread. I am more concerned about `acceptEither` i.e stage2 thread.

Comment: @Slaw -  You(slaw) said, `you've told it to be executed by one of the thread in the common ForkJoinPool`.  <-  by using `supplyAsync` i.e stage1 which got executed in worker-3, I can only infer that subsequent non Async stages can get executed in `main` or `worker-3` but not from the thread pool of which `worker-3` is part of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be clearer if you don't do everything inline. For example:

```java
// You used 'supplyAsync', which means the 'Supplier' will be executed
// using the common ForkJoinPool (any available thread from that pool)
CompletableFuture<Integer> stage1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    System.out.println("Stage 1: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return 40;
});

// You used 'supplyAsync' *again*, which means the 'Supplier' will be executed
// using the common ForkJoinPool (any available thread from that pool)
CompletableFuture<Integer> stage2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    System.out.println("Stage 2: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return 80;
});

/*
 * Both 'stage1' and 'stage2' have been set to execute using the common
 * ForkJoinPool. The use of 'acceptEither', or even 'acceptEitherAsync',
 * has no bearing on that. Because you used 'acceptEither', the
 * **CONSUMER** will be executed by the same thread which finished 'stage1'
 * or the same thread that finished 'stage2', whichever happens first,
 * or the caller thread (typically if 'stage1' and/or 'stage2' are already
 * complete by the time 'acceptEither' is invoked).
 */
stage1.acceptEither(stage2, result -> {
    System.out.println("Stage acceptEither: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    System.out.println("Result = " + result);
});
```

Note: `supplyAsync` has an overload that accepts an `Executor`, allowing you to specify a thread pool other than the common `ForkJoinPool`. The same is true for all the `xxxAsync` methods.

Comment: `You used 'supplyAsync' *again*, which means the 'Supplier' will be executed
using the common ForkJoinPool`. I should have considered this. +1 thanks.